# What does the '&' symbol in front of a variable do?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, methods

I've been going through some open-source code for a Twitter app, and came across this:

(in the OADataFetcher.h)  file:

```
OAMutableURLRequest *request;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData;
```

(inside the 'fetchDataWithRequest:delegate:didFinishSelector:didFailSelector:' method) in OADataFetcher.m:

```
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
```

I was wondering if someone can please explain to me what the '&' symbol does in front of the returningResponse and error variables. How is it different then simply using the variables without the ampersand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378195/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The & is the "address-of" operator.  It returns the address of (pointer to) the variable it precedes.

Comment: would i have gotten the same result if i just passed in 'response' and 'error'?

Comment: @dpigera - No, because then you're passing the value of the variable instead of the memory address.  The compiler should at least give a warning if you try it.