# Pass value as reference in Kotlin

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to convert code Objective C to Kotlin multiplatform
This is Objective C code

```
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    BOOL isDir;
    BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
    BOOL success = false;

    if (isDir && exists) {
        NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSError *error = nil;
        success = [pathUrl setResourceValue:isExcluded
                                     forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                      error:&error];

        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Could not exclude AsyncStorage dir from backup %@", error);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

In above code variable `isDir` use & when pass to function `fileExistsAtPath`
So how can I use `isDir` like that in Kotlin. I know this is
[address-of unary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378195/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-objective-c)

Can I use

```
  val isDir: CPointer<BooleanVar /* = kotlinx.cinterop.BooleanVarOf<kotlin.Boolean> */>? = null
        val exists = fileManager?.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDir)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a pointer in Kotlin, you need `memScoped`, inside this scope you can call `alloc` to create a pointer of any type.

Here's how you code can be written in Kotlin:

```kotlin
return memScoped {
    val fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager
    val isDir = alloc<BooleanVar>()
    val exists = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory = isDir.ptr)
    var success = false
    if (exists && isDir.value) {
        val pathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        val error = alloc<ObjCObjectVar<NSError?>>()
        success = pathUrl.setResourceValue(isExcluded, forKey = NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error = error.ptr)
        if (!success) {
            println("Could not exclude AsyncStorage dir from backup ${error.value}")
        }
    }
    return@memScoped success
}
```

Comment: I updated my question can you help my check

Comment: @Anhdevit I'm not sure what's your updated question. In your code you're passing `null` to `fileExistsAtPath`, but you need to pass a pointer. I showed you exactly how to you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass lambda and change bool value in it

```kotlin
var isDir: Boolean = false
fileExistsAtPath(onChange = { newValue -> isDir = newValue })
```

but I think this is NOT a good approach. Try to create `data class` with 2 fields: `isDir` and `exists`, or use `Pair` at least. And return them from function `fileExistsAtPath`

Comment: I updated my question can you help my check

Comment: @Anhdevit probably, you can use, but it's not what kotlin developer expects to see in code and I don't see the reason to choose this particular method instead of ones mentioned above. Maybe some context will help me understand why you want to use variable reference in kotlin

Comment: `fileExistsAtPath` is a system function, we can't change it signature.